# Double bar in plot axis annotation (e.g. ||k|| )?

Tags: r, plot

I can't figure out how to use the Euclidean norm symbol in R plot annotation. (I am aware of plotmath and use it). Anyone can help?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a (reproducible example)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Unicode symbol 2016](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2016/index.htm):

```
plot(1:10,1:10,xlab=expression("\u2016"*x*"\u2016"))
```

This works for me with X11 graphics under Ubuntu with an en_CA.utf8 locale, but you might have some trouble getting it exported portably under PDF etc. (maybe try the PDF driver from the `Cairo` package ...).  An alternative would be to use TikZ, but that has a lot of overhead too ...

Comment: Simple and nice, didn't realize that I can put the unicode character directly. Thanks!

Comment: btw, for me it gets perfectly exported to pdf with the function cairo_pdf() instead of the usual pdf()

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me on Windows 7. Probably has something to do with my fonts... but `plot(1:10,1:10,xlab=expression("||"*x*"||"))` works though. I'm guessing that isn't quite the same but looks good enough to me.